# Neo4j: Unable to load NODE with id

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to do a count on relationship:

```
MATCH (b:Buyer)-[r:VIEW]->(s:Supplier) RETURN COUNT(r);
```

It returns the error:

> Unable to load NODE with id 43813085

It seems I have imported some invalid node but how to identify and remove?

Comment: Which version of neo4j are you using? There was a known bug in versions prior to 2.3 which had the same error message (not sure it's exactly the same thing you're experiencing though...)

Comment: does such a node exist? do you do concurrent delete operations? 'MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 43813085 RETURN n`

Comment: I'm getting the same error with version 3.0.1. The node definitely exists.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try counting like this:

`RETURN size((:Buyer)-[:VIEW]->(:Supplier))`

Note that there are no identifiers in the query.

To delete the node, you can run this:

`MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 43813085 DETACH DELETE n`

or on older versions:

`MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 43813085 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE r, n`